# Combine like Polynomial Terms in stored in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a link list that each node stores the next node and the term. The term stores the coefficient, variable, and exponent. I need to iterate through the list and combine all like terms returning the first node with all others attached to it. I'm not even 100% sure if I am starting in the right place.

```
    node_t * combine_like_terms(const node_t * current_node_ptr) {
    if(current_node_ptr == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
//    node_t * start_node = current_node_ptr;
    const node_t * curr = current_node_ptr;
    node_t * newnodelist = NULL;
    int maxexponent = 0;
    
    do{
        term_t *t = curr->term;
        
        if(curr->term->exponent > maxexponent)
        {
          maxexponent = t->exponent;
        }
    }while((curr = curr->next_node));
    
    puts("Max exp: \n");
    curr = current_node_ptr;
    for(int i = 0; i <= maxexponent; i++){
        int coefficient = 0;
         do{
             term_t *x = curr->term;
           if(x->exponent == i){
                 coefficient += x->coefficient;
           }
         }while((curr = curr->next_node));
         
        term_t * terms = malloc(sizeof(term_t));
           terms->coefficient = coefficient;
           terms->var = 'x';
           terms->exponent = i;
          add_node(&newnodelist,terms);
         
    }
    return newnodelist;
    
}
```

due to some circumstances outside of my control the method return type and arguments can't be changed. My current idea is to find the highest exponent, then to go back through and find all coefficients with of each individual exponent and add them then add those new terms to a list. **I am getting a segmentation fault before the puts("Max Exp: \n");** that I do not know that cause of.

Comment: Regarding the segfault, use the debugger, step over the program while watching all the variables, and see where exactly it happens and why. If you want debugging help, please post a [mcve].